# Display images in both portrait and landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I currently have a fairly straight forward UI which displays three 250 x 180 images in UIImageView's but I want to be able to show them in a more interesting way and also when the ipad is rotated to landscape mode the images overlap the text etc.  It just looks a bit cheap.

What are my options for displaying this three images more creatively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determine what the best way to display images for both orientations are. Depending on how different things need to be, you got 3 basic options:

1) The difference are small, you just need to tweak positioning. This can usually be accomplished by adjusting the images struts and springers on the layout tab of at the nib editor.

2) You need to rearrange things to make more sense when rotated. In this case, implement willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and adjust the position of your images in this method. The changes will be animated automatically, so it usually already looks good even for simple adjustments.

3) You want to give the user a completely different experience in both orientations. In this case you might want to make separate view controllers for both orientations. There are quite a few tutorials to be found if you need this approach.

If its just a matter of placing the images in a way that they will fit, option 2 is probably the most suitable one.

Comment: Great thanks for your advice - I am thinking maybe I need to read a tutorial so if you have time please post it.  I like the thought of using option 3 because then I can arrange things properly - might get a bit messy though since I am using a nav controller

Comment: If its the root level then it will get messy. However when it's not the root, you can simply push the right view on the stack.

Comment: It's not the root no - so I would pop the the one view and push the other one.  cheers